# Why isn’t my Mac charging with 60 Watts?

Tags: macbook-pro, charging

[image]

The Adapter is 61W Apple Adapter.

Comment: Do you want to be able to use the machine while it charges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your laptop is turned on - this means that it is consuming energy. That energy is subtracted from the number of watts you're charging the battery with.

If you want to charge faster, a sure way is to shutdown the laptop or put it into sleep mode, before charging.

Comment: Does the Mac draw the full rating of the charger when off? Or is some of the power rating reserved to cater for maximum consumption: e.g. playing games with a USB device attached....? Because if you used an 85W charger, the Mac wouldn't draw more power, so perhaps this Mac's draw for charging is a max of 40W.

Comment: The Mac will draw the most it can when it is off. The most it can is not necessarily the full rating of the charger. In addition, it is possible that it will draw less power than max when the battery is near a full charge.

Comment: This particular Mac does not have a max of 40W. It can charge with 61W.

Comment: None of the power rating is "reserved" as such... the system will dynamically accomodate  loads such as plugging in USB devices, etc.